# Error deserializing JSON into list of objects

Tags: c#, json

Given the following json (it's a file called database.json in the root of the project):

```json
{
  "customers": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bob"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mary"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Joe"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the following customer class

```cs
public class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Getting an error while deserializing:

```cs
private List<Customer> GetCustomersFromFile()
{
    string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"database.json", Encoding.UTF8);
    return GetJsonGenericType<List<Customer>>(jsonString);
}

private static T GetJsonGenericType<T>(string json)
{
    var generatedType = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(generatedType, typeof(T));
}
```

Error details:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GroceryStoreAPI.Models.Customer]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
  Source=System.Text.Json
  StackTrace:
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleStartObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at GroceryStoreAPI.Data.CustomerRepo.GetJsonGenericType[T](String json) in C:\Users\iamau\source\repos\interview-dotnet3\GroceryStoreAPI\Data\CustomerRepo.cs:line 40
   at GroceryStoreAPI.Data.CustomerRepo.GetCustomersFromFile() in C:\Users\iamau\source\repos\interview-dotnet3\GroceryStoreAPI\Data\CustomerRepo.cs:line 33
   at GroceryStoreAPI.Data.CustomerRepo..ctor() in C:\Users\iamau\source\repos\interview-dotnet3\GroceryStoreAPI\Data\CustomerRepo.cs:line 18

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    GroceryStoreAPI.Data.CustomerRepo.GetJsonGenericType<T>(string) in CustomerRepo.cs
    GroceryStoreAPI.Data.CustomerRepo.GetCustomersFromFile() in CustomerRepo.cs
    GroceryStoreAPI.Data.CustomerRepo.CustomerRepo() in CustomerRepo.cs
```

I've tried Json.Net and got a similar error.

I also get an error doing something like this as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59098553/16287566):

```cs
string json_object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonString);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json_object);
```

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.'
```

Comment: Your json is not a list of customers. It contains a property `customers` that contains a list of items. You need to create a rootObject that has customers as the property and type is List of Customers... then deserialize to that rootObject.

Comment: Thanks @Jawad. I don't quite follow. Can you clarify what that root object would look like?

Answer (score 1):

The given JSON describes an **object** (starting/ending with curly braces `{...}`).

There are a lot of JSON to C# class generators out there and Visual Studio is shipped by default with such a tool.

Using https://json2csharp.com/ it will output the following lines from the given JSON:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Customer
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Customer> customers { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically @Jawad is saying below:

Create new class called "CustomerList" and try that.

```
public class CustomerList
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

private List<Customer> GetCustomersFromFile()
{
  string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"database.json", Encoding.UTF8);
  return GetJsonGenericType<List<CustomerList>>(jsonString);
}

private static T GetJsonGenericType<T>(string json)
{
  var generatedType = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
   return (T)Convert.ChangeType(generatedType, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: This will not compile.